# PHP file_get_contents from file in same directory

Tags: php, file-get-contents, relative-path

I have an API written in PHP that returns some JSON.  I would like to get this JSON and use it in a different PHP file in the same directory on the server.

Here is the relative url.

```
$newUrl = "getcomment.php?cat=books&q=".$payload;
```

How can I get its contents?

I tried:

```
$result = file_get_contents($newUrl);
$decodedresult =  json_decode($result, true);
```

However result comes back empty

I also tried

```
$json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . $newUrl);
echo $json;
```

but this also comes back empty

It seems that getting the value from a relative url path is slightly tricker than from a fully qualified url.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can use curl for that.

Comment: Can you separate the generation of the JSON (or the basic data) from the page returning the JSON.  This will allow you to directly get the JSON from any page and save having to do a web call to fetch some data from your own application

Comment: I probably could but the page returning the JSON currently is already written and used as an endpoint for another api so would like to reuse this code/resource rather than duplicating

Comment: PHP scripts are only executed when they're accessed through the webserver. If you access it as a local file with `file_get_contents`, it just returns the source code, it doesn't execute it.

Comment: You dont have to duplicate anything, you are simply trying to reuse too big part of your code. Just extract the code that generates the json and call it from the endpoint as well as from your new use case.

Comment: @Barmar so file_get_contents cannot work period?

Comment: @slepic, pretty much all the code in the other file is needed. That is the module of code for this case.  Are you suggesting extracting it into a function?

Comment: What is the last way?  Fully qualified with http://?

Comment: Yes. You've apparently edited the question and removed that, which is why I deleted my comment.

Comment: I also endorse sleptic's suggestion that you extract the code into a function. You can use `require("filename.php")` in both scripts to load the function. One of them calls the function and assigns the result to a variable, the other one calls the function and echoes the result.

Comment: Actually, it would be better if the function just returned the array, not JSON. One script can then `echo json_encode($result)`, the other can just use the results directly.

Comment: I deleted my edit cause now I can't get that to work either. Not sure if I introduced typo or a different loop of code was returning the json earlier.

Comment: The function takes a bunch of arguments so I can't just  include but I guess I can put function in other file and include or require it, then call it.

Comment: @zztop yes thats exactly what I am suggesting, even with what Barmar suggests, if the other use case is going to json decode the encoded data, then this part can also be omitted, only the code that is common for both use cases should be moved to separate function.